# Force changing the ip of the Heroku dyno

Tags: heroku, ip-address, dyno

I am wondering if there is a way to reset the dyno IP on Heroku when *I* want.

I noticed sometimes it changes when the application is restarted. However, not always.

How can we reset the dyno IP address on restart every time?

---

I already saw these questions:

- [Does Heroku change dyno IP during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22535898/1420197)
- https://www.quora.com/Do-Heroku-dynos-get-new-IP-addresses-when-redeployed-or-restarted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out by restarting the app (deleting the dynos), the IP is changed, by default.

You can do this [by using the Heroku API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-restart-all).

Comment: This does indeed appear to work. For some reason Mailchimp blacklisted one of the IP's used by Heroku, but restarting our app must have given us a different IP for now it's no longer blocked.